# Setting up mysql in path on OSX so it's included everytime I open terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, mysql, path

I have installed mysql on my OSX 10.11 and I want to run it from the terminal, so I need to add it to my path. I have created a `.bash_profile` file in my home directory with the contents `export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"` in it, but I still have to run `source .bash_profile` when I open up a new terminal session. How can I permanently include mysql in my path for every new terminal session without having to write a command at the start of the session?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I forgot to tell that I use ZSH, which means that I should not use `.bash_profile` but `.zshrc` instead. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to your .bash_profile file.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

You can do this easily with the following command, which will append the line if the file already exists or create a new file with the line if it doesn't.

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

- Close current terminal and reopen it.
- Finished. Now terminal will not asks again for path.